# Change PayPal account in PayPal app

Tags: paypal

I've created a PayPal app on a new account. I am accepting payments in a sandbox environment using REST API. It's all working. But when it comes to live environment, I need change an account which will receive real payments. Is it possible, or I have to create a PayPal app on that account, which suppose to receive real payments?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use different account for live payments. You will need to login to https://developer.paypal.com with that account's login. Then, create a new REST app or use an existing one if any. On top right corner, there are tabs displaying Sandbox | Live. Select Live. Then, use the client ID and secret for live environment.

Also, make sure that the account has permission to run whatever operation you want to use in live environment. Go to My Account menu on the left side to check it out.